# What's the proper HTTP response code for shipping unavailable?

Tags: api, rest, http

I'm developing a REST API that processes orders. Along with the order details, the consumer has to post the shipping addresses. Sometimes, we just can't ship to these addresses.

What's the proper HTTP Code for this situation? I've been reading [this](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), but didn't found something that fits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be looking at [RFC 7231, Section 6.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6) for up-to-date documentation on HTTP status codes.

The service should respond with `400 Bad Request`, since the request being made is invalid - you cannot do what the client has asked. You would need to include a response document that contains the details of the failure.

Additionally, a hypermedia API might provide a mechanism to test the shipping address in independence of making the order as a means for clients to detect a problem with invalid addresses before performing the request to process the order, such as building up an order in several steps and including a call to assign a delivery address.

Comment: 400 looks pretty rude but I'm guessing it's OK. The addresses are being validated in the same API call. The reasons for not being able to ship might not only be invalid addresses though. That's why "Bad Request" seems a little bit too much for this. But I'll trust you!